On a Micronaut Kafka listener, does autoStartup = false mean it's "paused"?
I have a listener like this:
@KafkaListener( groupId = "mylistener", autoStartup = false )
And a scheduled job that contains:
consumerRegistry.isPaused("mylistener")
This returns false, but I expected it to be true.
I saw where these options were introduced, but it doesn't appear to be documented.
I really want to be able to delay a listener starting up, run some code first and enable the listener(once and only once)
I tried debugging and looking through Github issues

It means it's not started at all, which matches your use case. The consumer can be started later manually, after you run whatever needs running.

But I don't know the state of it when it starts up as false.  If I resume it and pause it, then isPaused is true.   There's no other boolean to use it seems.
